# Android Studio 2.3 update : Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-apt, annotation-processor

So, I have read all the questions I could find on this site regarding this issue. I have also had a chat in comments with one of the developer with similar issue, who was able to solve it.

I dont have apt or annotationProcessor written any where in my gradle scripts.

I dont have the word android-apt written anywhere in my code. I even went ahead and checked out all the libraries. That were included in my project.

This is a really big problem and needs to be solved.

I am attaching the modified build.gradle below, Please suggest :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion


    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.legalimpurity.indiancourts"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true;
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
//            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }



}
//For Facebook i guess
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
def var = dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'


    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"



    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

//    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'


    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'


    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

//    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'


//    compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:2.3.6'

    compile 'com.hkm:hkmprocessbuttons:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.6'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
//    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
//    compile 'com.zaihuishou:expandablerecycleradapter-databinding:1.0.0'
//    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//    compile 'com.legalimpurity.expandablerecyclerview:expandable-recyclerview:1.0'
    compile project(':agendacalendarview')
    compile project(':expandablelibrary')
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'

}
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Older versions of Realm use `android-apt`. You should upgrade your `realm-android` plugin version.

Comment: Wooh Amazing ! Thanks ! I checked all my dependencies, not classpath libraries !

Comment: @botteap I got this warning with realm-android plugin to 2.1.1, so I upgraded it to 2.2.0, but then I got 
`Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()'`
Do you know any way to fix this ?

Comment: My guess is that you are still using the old Realm plugin for some reason. I don't use Realm myself so I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
```

with

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.2"
```

and then apply plugin

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```