# android-apt incompatible with gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-apt

I originally had an error with gradle when I updated gradle about android apt. I went online and Googled what was wrong. I read that apt was no longer supported and I migrated my code accordingly and then went to rebuild.

However, now I'm getting this error even after migrating my code and removing all android apt codes and converting them to annotations

`Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.`

This is my `build.gradle` file for that module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 1
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 11 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ltst.schoolapp.teacher"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../teacher/distribution/schoolappteacher.keystore')
            storePassword "LtStSchoolappTeacher"
            keyAlias "teacherreleasekey"
            keyPassword "UgoTeacher"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            versionNameSuffix '-dev'
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.23'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation project(path: ':core')

    //    compile 'com.layer.sdk:layer-sdk:0.20.3'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    //    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.5.8'
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk'))
            output.outputFileName = "schoolapp-teacher-${output.name}.apk"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please show us your other gradle files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.3 update : Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736720/android-studio-2-3-update-warningusing-incompatible-plugins-for-the-annotatio)

Comment: I updated the realm dependency. Still giving me same error